# shoot bullet with mouse

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

```
    double bullet::distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    return sqrt( pow( x2 - x1, 2 ) + pow( y2 - y1, 2 ) );
}
```

distance function ^

```
speedX.push_back((x - targetx) / distance(x, y, targetx, targety)*7);//x player pos, targetx mouse pos
speedY.push_back((y - targety) / distance(x, y, targetx, targety)*7);
```

calculating how many pixels change every 8ms ^

```
sbullet[i].setX(sbullet[i].getX() - (int)round(speedX[i]));
sbullet[i].setY(sbullet[i].getY() - (int)round(speedY[i]));
```

actual moving ^

So this is my bullet going with mouse, but it doesn't go EXACTLY to mouse.

How can I make it more accuarate ?

Comment: "_but it's quite inaccurate_" Could you share with us what you witnessed? And what do you mean by "_it sometimes hits mouse_"? Also things like `x - targetx` and `sbullet[i].getX() - (int)round(speedX[i])` without handling `negative` exceptions is a problem, are you sure you need is as it is and not the **absolute values**?

Comment: Just an aside - a more convenient way of computing cartesian distance is using [`std::hypot`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot). So this would be `std::hypot(x2-x1, y2-y1)` in your case.

Comment: it doesn't go EXACTLY to mouse, it's missing it, if you still don't understand i can download game if you want :/

Comment: How can i handle these negative exceptions ? it was working, so i didn't saw that as a problem ;D

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury thanks for bringing `std::hypot` to my attention!

Comment: My bets are on the weird rounding in your third snippet. Integer coordinates can only do so much when you're dealing with arbitrary directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to slow down once you get to the mouse. In your code, you always move 7 pixels in the direction of the target. If you are less than 7 pixels away, you overshoot.

You could add a statement such that if distance is less than 7, just set the new position to the target.